# VB.net How do I manually/explicitly convert an array to an ObjectCollection?

Tags: vb.net, casting

With strict=off  (project..project properties..strict=off), I can do

```
Dim Objects As Object = New Object() {"AAA", "BBB"}        
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Objects)
```

But if I do strict=on then it tells me

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub AddRange(items() As Object)': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to '1-dimensional array of Object'.
    'Public Sub AddRange(value As 

System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.
```

Often with these converts that would be implicit with strict=off, when I then turn strict=on, the compilation error tells me what to change it to. But here it doesn't suggest anything.

I want to keep strict=on (at least for the purpose of learning this)

How do convert it explicitly so it doesn't give that compilation error. So I can get those two lines to work with strict=on ?

**Added Clarification**

I see now that I missed parentheses.  So i'll clarify my question. The issue is this-

If I do this line

```
 Dim nums As Integer = {4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Then I get a compilation error, even with strict=off  it cannot compile it

On the other hand this

```
dim obj as Object = {4,5,6,7]
```

That line above, will compile with strict=off  because even though the right hand side is an array of objects, that either is an object or can be converted into an object.

If I do strict=off then it works, so VB is doing some casting to make it work. i.e. true it cannot convert an array of integer, into an integer. But it can (it seems) convert an array of objects into an object.

i.e. When the compiler saw      `Dim nums As Integer = {4, 5, 6, 7}`  and strict=off it didn't say "ah he missed a parentheses" and convert it to dim nums as Integer() = {4,5,6,7}.  Likewise i'm sure it doesn't do it with `dim object as Object = {3,4,5,6}`   but it did something in the object case, to make it work. And it did it implicitly.

I want to see what that is, explicitly, I want to see what it is to add to that , that the copiler would add to it, to do that casting, to make it work. And whatever it is, it isn't adding parentheses.

Comment: Since it contains strings, why not create a string array?  `Dim items As String() = {"AAA", "BBB"}`  you dont need `New Object()` if it is a local declaration

Comment: @Plutonix I see I can.. I was just experimenting, but yeah I probably should have. What is the difference between using New and not using New, e.g. how does it affect local/global declaration?

Comment: With Option Infer on, VB can infer that your new array is string from the contents of the literal;  form/module level initializers still need it though.

Comment: @Plutonix The thing is I missed a ()  and if I do the () then it works. So the question is.. and i'll edit my question to clarify this. How do I cast an object into a collection of objects, and an array of objects, into an object?

Comment: @Plutonix and since it compiles with strict=off  and fails with strict=on, even without `new`, so the `new` doesn't make a difference here. But good to know it was unnecessary to write `new`.

Comment: First, forget `Option Strict Off` it is not for serious programming.  Second, the `()` are part of the declaration - they say *I want an array*; `Dim nums As Integer() = {4, 5, 6, 7}` declares nums as an integer array.  I am not sure what *kind* of object collection you are after, but an array is not a collection and trying to directly set a listbox collection wont work - it is read only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81203/discussion-between-barlop-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 1):

Just add parens after your `As Object`:

```
Dim Objects As Object() = New Object() {"AAA", "BBB"}
```

The reason is that you're declaring `Objects` as an `Object`, not an array of `Objects`.  Note, you could also do this:

```
Dim Objects = New Object() {"AAA", "BBB"}
```

Additionally, I would recommend you adhere to naming conventions and name your variable lowercase `object`:

```
Dim objects = New Object() {"AAA", "BBB"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the parentheses to declare it correctly.  But that makes me wonder.. When I had strict=off, what implicit conversion was happening that made `Dim Objects As Object = New Object() {"AAA", "BBB"}`  compile without the parentheses?

Comment: e.g. is strict=off so unstrict that it saw my code, spotted I missed parentheses and added them?  Or, more likely, is it doing some explicit conversion that makes it compile? and if so, then what conversion is it doing?